# Sencha Touch: Store without proxy

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have been wandering on the internet for a basic question regarding Sencha Touch Stores.
The question is , If we don't use any proxy like WebSQL, localstorage etc for the store then where is the data stored? Or Where can we view the data?

**Elaboration Of My question**

I have created a store like this.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.UserPass',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config:{
   model:'MyApp.model.UP',
   storeId:'UserPasswords',
   //no proxy
}
});
```

At runtime , I add some data in the store using

```
Ext.getStore('UserPass').add({param1 : "data1" , param2 : "data2"});
```

Then I binds this store to a List. Everything works fine.
But the question is where is the data stored w.r.t to storage i.e in program's memory, browser's memory, nowhere or somewhere?
May be It looks like a silly question, but the answer of it would help me in understanding a lot of related concepts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a proxy for your store, the proxy will default to `Ext.data.proxy.Memory`. Take a look at the code of the `applyProxy` method of `Ext.data.Store`. So there will never be a store without a proxy.